# In T-SQL, does <> '?' mean something other than data not equal to a question mark?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been excluding records in a query where a number of text fields only contain a question mark. My code ended thus:

```
AND Address1 <> '?'
AND Address2 <> '?'
AND Address3 <> '?'
```

Unfortunately, a lot of other records (that had NULL values in the above address fields) were also being excluded - records I actually needed. I took out Addres2 & 3, and get more records than I suspect I need, but it now works.
So, my question is this: does the <>'?' part signify anything else anywhere in T-SQL?

Comment: That is because nothing ever equals NULL. So NULL <> ? evaluates to NULL. So if you want to include NULL you would have to use coalesce(Address1, '') <> '?'

Comment: Unfortunately SQL server handles NULL in the way as they are not values so you can't compare them against values, they are usually treated as unknown according to documentation.

Comment: @MichelHanna - It's not SQL Server that defines this behaviour, it's the SQL standards themselves.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Specifically, is it in an SSIS package?

Comment: @MatBailie Yes i mean here that the engine handles it in that way but not meant with defining standards for sure. it's nice to mention that also and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

`<>` means "not equal not", so something like `'abc' <> 'def'` would evaluate to `TRUE`. In regards to `NULL`, however, you can't use boolean operators. Using a boolean operator with a `NULL` returns the result `NULL` (effectively unknown), which isn't true; and (to state the obvious) a clause is only true if it's true. So, as a result something like `'abc' <> NULL` = `NULL != TRUE`; meaning that the `WHERE` clause requirements are not met.

To deal with `NULL` you need to use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators. So, for your SQL you would need:

```
AND (Address1 <> '?' OR Address1 IS NULL)
AND (Address2 <> '?' OR Address2 IS NULL)
AND (Address3 <> '?' OR Address3 IS NULL)
```

(Assuming you want rows with `NULL` returned).

As Sean commented, you *can* wrap columns like `Address1` with the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function (i.e. `ISNULL(Address1,'') <> '?'`), however, I recommend against that. Using those functions within your `WHERE` would make your query non-SARGable and could have (severe) performance impacts on your query as a result.

Comment: Kudos mate!! Not sure why I glossed over the SARGability factor. +10 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in believing that `<>` means "not equal to". What you're missing out on is that `NULL` doesn't equal anything, and also doesn't *not equal* anything (not even other `NULL` values). Any equality comparison to `NULL` actually evaluates to "Unknown" which is not the same as either True or False.

```
NULL = '?' -- evaluates to Unknown
NULL <> '?' -- evaluates to Unknown
NULL = NULL -- evaluates to Unknown
NULL <> NULL -- evaluates to Unknown
```

If you want to include `NULL` records in your result, you need to compare using `IS NULL`. Change your statements to this:

```
AND (Address1 <> '?' OR Address1 IS NULL)
AND (Address2 <> '?' OR Address2 IS NULL)
AND (Address3 <> '?' OR Address3 IS NULL)
```

Comment: My understanding is that such operations involving NULL don't evaluate to some 'unknown' concept, they evaluate to NULL.  *(Same consequence, but no need to introduce 'unknown')*

Comment: Actually, it's important to introduce 'unknown' because in most programming languages, like C, C++, C#, etc., "Null" is a value, usually zero, and can be tested for equality.

The concept in SQL is that "NULL" means "Unknown"... if you have something unknown in one box, and something unknown in another box, there's no way to know that they're equal. Or even not equal. YOU DON'T KNOW. Which is the point. It helps you think about SQL NULL properly.

Comment: And let's add some documentation about [null and unknown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)